# MacroError VS. Err in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

When would you use `MacroError` in Access VBA code?

I have always used the `Err` object for error handling. I recently came across some VBA code that had uses the `MacroError` object instead. I read the MS doc on this object and it has a note:

> The MacroError object does not contain information about run-time errors that occur when running Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) code.

Which is odd because the usage of `MacroError` I was looking at was in a VBA procedure and it was used right after a `DoCmd` call to check `If MacroError.Number <> 0`. Shouldn't we use `Err` for this?

REFERENCE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.macroerror

Comment: The documentation seems inconsistent: "When an error occurs in a macro, information about the error is stored in the MacroError object ... The MacroError object does not contain information about run-time errors that occur when running Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) code."

Comment: Looking at it a bit more, it seems that these are for [non-VBA macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-macros-A39C2A26-E745-4957-8D06-89E0B435AAC3) so trying to use them as an alternative for `Err` in VBA code is misguided. The VBA `MacroError` object seems to be for use-cases when you are using both VBA and non-VBA macros.

Comment: Thanks John. I wouldn't do that. I have replaced that code with my normal error handling code. Your comment might be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Macros have the ability to flow in to VBA and back again.

The `MacroError` object allows you to check for errors in the macro part from VBA.

If you are only using VBA you would never need this. For VBA only you would stick with the regular `Err` object for your error handling.

If you had an error in a macro, and then an error in VBA, you could end up with two different errors being held in each object.